# Different controllers for each view in a directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to separate my controller logic for each view in a directory rather than have all of it in one controller because I don't want that many actions in one. Any way to achieve this?

```
Views--
    FooFolder
            Fooview.cshtml
            Barview.cshtml


Controllers--
    FooController.cs
    BarController.cs
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: You could use a partial class -- it would at least separate the logic into multiple files.  I like keep my controllers slim so I don't really run into this with having too much logic...

Comment: Shouldn't Barview.cshtml be in a BarFolder? The convention is to have one Views folder for each Controller, right? So, knock yourself out creating Controllers and View folders.

Comment: With partial classes, as @JohnKalberer suggests, you wouldn't have so many folders. You could see all the different sub-Controllers (partial classes) in Solution Explorer, but all of the associated Views would remain in one folder.

Comment: Not worried about too much logic. Just want to keep the controllers lightweight with action methods. These views will have a number of event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no* requirement to have views in a certain folder or actions in a certain controller. It's just a convention, and you can change it, either by, e.g., replacing the view engine or changing route definitions or by explicitly specifying view paths. However, if you want to separate controller logic the place to start isn't with the controller itself, but by offloading the logic into business methods elsewhere and calling that from the controller.

Comment: Agreed.  And if you find that your controller actions are getting bloating with logic then I recommend that you watch the [putting your controllers on a diet](http://www.viddler.com/v/b568679c) video.

Comment: It's not about offloading logic. I'll have a number of views with a number of events to handle and it would be nice to keep the action methods to a smaller number per controller, and I may want to inject services into the controllers for some and not others.